# UITableViewCell Duplicate Behavior With UIButton SetTitle And Cell Reuse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'm getting some really unusual behavior with my application. I have a tableview that loads cells based on data from a server, The data coming from the server is great, no duplicates and is how it should be. However as I scroll through my table I'm noticing UIButtons that I use setTitle on are showing duplicate title that were previously shown while scrolling, as if the reused cells aren't updating the title in some cases when setTitle is called..

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DETAILED_TAGS_FEED_CELL_IDENTIFIER];
NSDictionary *tag = [self.tags objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

ArgumentButton *nameButton = (ArgumentButton *)[cell viewWithTag:DETAILED_TAGS_FEED_CELL_TAG_NAME];
[nameButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tagSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[nameButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@", [tag objectForKey:@"tag"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
nameButton.argument = [tag objectForKey:@"tag"];

UILabel *totalFollowersLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:DETAILED_TAGS_FEED_CELL_TAG_TOTAL_FOLLOWERS];
totalFollowersLabel.text = [tag objectForKey:@"followers"];

UILabel *followersLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:DETAILED_TAGS_FEED_CELL_TAG_FOLLOWERS];

UIView *dividerView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:DETAILED_TAGS_FEED_CELL_DIVIDER];

UILabel *totalProductsLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:DETAILED_TAGS_FEED_CELL_TAG_TOTAL_PRODUCTS];
totalProductsLabel.text = [tag objectForKey:@"products"];

UILabel *productsLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:DETAILED_TAGS_FEED_CELL_TAG_PRODUCTS];

if (self.allowFollow) {
    totalFollowersLabel.frame = CGRectMake(30, totalFollowersLabel.frame.origin.y, totalFollowersLabel.frame.size.width, totalFollowersLabel.frame.size.height);
    followersLabel.frame = CGRectMake(30, followersLabel.frame.origin.y, followersLabel.frame.size.width, followersLabel.frame.size.height);

    dividerView.frame = CGRectMake(133, dividerView.frame.origin.y, dividerView.frame.size.width, dividerView.frame.size.height);

    totalProductsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(157, totalProductsLabel.frame.origin.y, totalProductsLabel.frame.size.width, totalProductsLabel.frame.size.height);
    productsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(157, productsLabel.frame.origin.y, productsLabel.frame.size.width, productsLabel.frame.size.height);

    NSString *followButtonTitle = ([[tag objectForKey:@"followed"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) ? @"Unfollow" : @"Follow";

    ArgumentButton *followButton = (ArgumentButton *)[cell viewWithTag:DETAILED_TAGS_FEED_CELL_TAG_FOLLOW];
    followButton.argument = indexPath;
    [followButton addTarget:self action:@selector(followSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [followButton setTitle:followButtonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    followButton.hidden = NO;
}

HorizontalScroll *scroll = (HorizontalScroll *)[cell viewWithTag:DETAILED_TAGS_FEED_CELL_TAG_SCROLL];
scroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 0);
scroll.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5);
scroll.pagingEnabled = NO;

[scroll resetItems];

NSArray *items = [tag objectForKey:@"items"];
NSMutableArray *scrollItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
    NSArray *scrollItemXIB = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetailedFeedScrollItemView" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *scrollItemView = [scrollItemXIB lastObject];

    ArgumentButton *itemButton = (ArgumentButton *)[scrollItemView viewWithTag:DETAILED_FEED_SCROLL_ITEM_TAG_BUTTON];
    [itemButton sd_setImageWithURL:[APIController resourceUrlForUserId:[item objectForKey:@"userId"] resourceName:[item objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [itemButton addTarget:self action:@selector(productSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    itemButton.argument = [item objectForKey:@"id"];

    [scrollItems addObject:scrollItemView];
}

[scroll loadItems:scrollItems];

return cell;
```

Note: I am using UITableViewCells within their own XIB for this, which is set like this in viewDidLoad.

```
[self registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DetailedTagsFeedTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:DETAILED_TAGS_FEED_CELL_IDENTIFIER];
```

It's as if [nameButton setTitle:] is not setting the right titles while scrolling? I've tried a little debugging by setting the followersLabel text equal to the same value that we're attempting to set with setTitle on the nameButton, and the value IS correct when setting the .text property of the label in the same cell.. Very confusing.

The Argument button class is nothing special. Just a simple subclass that has a public property for passing an argument with itself to a target/action.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but your code is very unreadable and hard to figure out. I strongly suggest that now is the right time to use a custom cell class already.

Comment: It looks like you're using a custom cell class, so why are you using tags instead of IBOutlets for all your subviews? Your code would be shorter and easier to read if you did so. I would also do away with the whole if (self.allowFollow) clause, and dequeue a different cell for that case with those subviews already set up correctly in a xib file.

Comment: ^ I just started converting everything to IBOutlets after realizing this. And thank you for the suggestion